# Cumulative sum based on 13 months and year in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

For a given month and year in a row the sum of the previous months value needs to calculated.
Month is considered as 13 here in this scenario.How to calculate the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a calculated column:

```
CumulativeSum = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( MyTable[Value] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( MyTable, MyTable[Year] ),
        MyTable[Month] < EARLIER ( MyTable[Month] )
    ) + MyTable[Value]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Olly, it does not work i get error that 
-
Earlier(mytable[Month]) - parameter is incorrect cannot find the name.

Comment: Test fine for me - see image added to answer